# php imagick - can't merge cmyk image with tranparency image

Tags: php, imagick

I have a cmyk image
I want to put on this image another image (png image with transparent background)
and merge them to a new cmyk image.
My code works well, but instead of transparent color I get a white color.

This is my code:

```
        <?php

    function create_order_item_image($background_url) {
        $image = new Imagick();
        $draw = new ImagickDraw();
        $pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'transparent' );
        $option_width = 300;
        $option_height = 300;
        $image->newImage($option_width, $option_height, $pixel);
            
        $background = new Imagick();
        $image->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
        $background->readImage($background_url);
        $image = fromRGBtoCMYK($image);
        $image->setImageFormat('png');
        $image->setImageBackgroundColor("transparent");
        $image->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
        $background->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
        $background->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
        $background->scaleImage($option_width, $option_height);
        $image->compositeImage($background, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
        
        //This is the problametic image! All the transparent became white :(
        $details_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/concepta_orders_files/image.png'; 
        $details2 = new Imagick();
        $details2->readImage(str_replace(ABSPATH, (get_site_url(null, '', 'https') . '/'),$details_path));
        $details2->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
        $details2->setImageFormat('png');
        $details2->setImageBackgroundColor("transparent");
        $details2->scaleImage($option_width,  $option_height);
        $image->negateImage(false, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALL);
        $image->compositeImage($details2, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $blid, $blid);
                  
        $image->setImageFormat('png'); 
        $folder_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR. '/uploads/concepta_orders_files';
        if (!file_exists($folder_path)) {
            mkdir($folder_path, 0777, true);
        }
        $img_path = $folder_path . '/' . $fileName; 
        $image->writeImage($img_path);
        $image->clear();
        $image->destroy();
        return $img_path;
    }

    function fromRGBtoCMYK($img) {
         if ($img->getImageColorspace() == Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK) {
           $profiles = $img->getImageProfiles('*', false);
           // we're only interested if ICC profile(s) exist
           $has_icc_profile = (array_search('icc', $profiles) !== false);
           // if it doesnt have a CMYK ICC profile, we add one
           if ($has_icc_profile === false) {
               $icc_cmyk = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/icc_profiles/cmyk/USWebUncoated.icc');
               $img->profileImage('icc', $icc_cmyk);
               unset($icc_cmyk);
           }
           // then we add an RGB profile
           $icc_rgb = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/icc_profiles/sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc');
           $img->profileImage('icc', $icc_rgb);
           unset($icc_rgb);
        }
        $img->setImageChannelDepth(0,8);
        $img->stripImage (); // this will drop down the size of the image dramatically (removes all profiles)
        return $img;
    }
```

Before I add the function fromRGBtoCMYK -
The transparent didn't gone,
but I need the cmyk colors.

My problem in one sentence:
Can't merge png with transparent image -
to cmyk image.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Unless I’m reading your code incorrectly, you appear to be trying to save a PNG as CMYK which is not supported.

Comment: So what should I do? I  need to add to the cmyk - a png image layer.

Comment: If you need CMYK, I assume you are in the print world, so follow whatever the specs are, usually JPEG or TIFF. If you are making a web-preview, convert to RGB just for the preview.

Comment: My customer is in the print world,I am programmer. My software takes the CMYK file, adds another dynamic image (text with transparent background), and send the updated file to print. Can I make womething like this? That's what I try to do

Comment: As I keep saying, trying saving it to a file format that supports what you are looking for. JPEG doesn’t support transparency, but you are flattening, so that doesn’t matter. It, along with TIFF, are the too most common raster image formats with CMYK support. Also, just use whatever CMYK image format your client is giving you.

Comment: Really thank you for your response! This is the CMYK image https://concepta.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/316.jpg. On this image, I need to display this png image https://concepta.co.il/wp-content/uploads/concepta_orders_files/2288_option_1_text_1644262868.png. Like a watermark, it can't be jpeg, because like a watermark I need to see the bottom image under the text that in the top image.The customer wants the final result as CMYK image, he need it for print.

Comment: I’m on vacation right now, and don’t have easy access to test this, but I don’t see any reason why you can’t apply that to the JPEG. Yes, your PNG has transparency, but once added to the JPEG it should flatten out just fine. In the print world we literally call this transparency flattening.